# Pop coprocessor register to specific address

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to learn assembly and I am using NASM. Right now I am stuck with a situation where I want to pop from the coprocessor stack (using `FISTP`) into a memory location which address was calculated with `LEA`. So basically having these two instructions:

```
lea eax, [ebp - 4] ; EAX = The address where I want to write to
fistp  dword [eax] ; (?)
```

What I've been seeing is that the contents of `ST0` are written to `EAX`, but not to the address contained in `EAX`.
How can this be achieved?

An example would be super useful, I've been looking into manuals and references, but so far it all seems super cryptic to me. Assembler, architectures, registers... everything low level is still difficult to read and comprehend to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are somehow confused.  The FISTP dword [eax] will store the value at the address specified in the eax register.  Write a small program in assembler and step through it with your debugger to see it do that directly.  In particular, it is actually hard to get FP register values into the GP registers, without going through a memory location.

You can compute an address in one step, and use it in another as you have shown.  But the x86 addressing modes can do a lot in a single instruction.  This single instruction does what both of yours do:

```
    fistp dword [ebp -4 ]
```

It is worth your trouble to read about addressing modes in the Intel reference manuals carefully.

Frankly, its worth a day of your time to skim the [**Combined Volume Set of Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals**](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) (several volumes) to find out what is in them, so you know what you can learn more about, and where to look.  They even contain pretty good overviews.   Don't be daunted; persist, it will pay off big time.

Comment: Thanks. Your second sentence for some reason gave me the light to fix my code. I do have been looking at the manuals, but they're just too cryptic for me right now. So, I've been writing more and more code and going back to the docs. Things get clearer with each step, but there's a LOT of stuff to learn. The last paragraph in my question was intended to prevent "RTFM answers", given that I've read a lot of questions where the first thing everyone tells the OP is to not be lazy and/or stupid and go read (which I've been doing, just not getting it all, yet). Thank you for not going that route.

Comment: There's a lot to be said for tinkering, while RTFMing at the same time.  Yes, its confusing; it will take you a long time to understand why the Intel assembly language looks the way it does.  It took them 30+ years and many evolutionary steps; expect it to be convoluted and the only ultimate cure for that is those manuals.  But the overviews of the machine in those manuals *really* are pretty good.  They've had 30 years to write the manuals, too.